# Ember.js with devise on rails application : 406 Not Acceptable on sign up

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ember.js

I set up a rails 3.2.11 application using Devise for authentication. 
I want to use [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) as an mvc framework.

When I launch an ajax call to the POST /users.json route I get a 406 Not Acceptable.

Here is my ajax call :

```
urlBase : '/users'

signup : (username, email, password, passwordConfirmation) ->
  $.ajax
    url: "#{@.get('urlBase')}.json"
    type: "POST"
    dataType: "json"
    data:
      "user[username]": username
      "user[email]": email
      "user[password]": password
      "user[password_confirmation]": passwordConfirmation

    success: (data) ->
      alert('Completed sign up process: '+ JSON.stringify(data));
      @errorMsg = "Signed up successfully." 

    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
      alert "Error completing sign up: " + textStatus + " error: " + errorThrown
```

Here are the logs :

```
Started POST "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-14 14:38:57 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"obo", "email"=>"obo@obo.dv", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (1.3ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'obo@obo.dv' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 311ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

I do not understand why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zajn's answer explains that DeviseController now responds only to HTML format (since version 2.2.0).
The [changelog](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc) say to add the JSON format to the DeviseController.respond_to.

I did it subclassing SessionsController and RegistrationsController and adding respond_to :json :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json
end

class SessionsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.2  Better edit the config file.

Answer (score 4):

What version of Devise are you using?

I encountered a similar problem last week after accidentally upgrading to Devise 2.2.0. There were some backward incompatible changes made in that version, including a change that made `DeviseController` only respond to `HTML` by default. You can add additional formats such as `JSON` though, which should solve your issue.

Read about the Devise changes [on their changelog on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc). If you don't want to do that, try downgrading to Devise 2.1.2, which is what I did for the time being.

Comment: It's outlined in the changelog I believe. I believe it says to use `DeviseController.respond_to` to add a new format. I haven't yet done it myself, so I can't give you any example from my experience.