# Latest Active_Model_Serializers breaks Devise Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, active-model-serializers

I am doing some updates to a Rails app that one of our clients uses.

Long story short, it relies on Devise for authentication and Active Model Serializers for serializing data in our API.

The current version is using [a fork of Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/pushcx/active_model_serializers), which is on a fairly old version.  I required some functionality in the newest version of Active Model Serializers, so I changed the gem to look at [master](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).  Conveniently, the changes in the fork have since been added to the latest version of AMS, so I changed the syntax and all seemed well.

However, once I logged out of the site and logged back in, I realized that something was very broken.  As expected, a logged out user gets redirected to /users/sign_in.  Since the gem update, though, that page is now blank white - no header, no HTML, no nothing.  Just white.  I reverted to the old version of the gem to confirm that was the problem, and the /users/sign_in page worked wonderfully.

Checking my rails debug output, I show the following:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-25 11:15:05 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 76ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Anyone got some hints on why my views are all of a sudden blank?

### Additional Info

I'm not sure if this is related, but it's also interesting.  I tried cURLing the /users/sign_in page, and on cURL I get a JSON response.

```
{"user":{"id":null,"email":"","name":null}}
```

This does not come through on a regular browser.

__

In my routes, I have the following line that maps Devise to /users, and overrides the registration controller.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}
```

The registration controller looks like:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :redirect_unless_admin

  private
  def redirect_unless_admin
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, inevitably as soon as I post the question I always find the answer immediately.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319868/ember-js-with-devise-on-rails-application-406-not-acceptable-on-sign-up) the recent versions of Devise only have a `respond_to` on `:html` by default.

The normal issue for this is that people can't get Devise's JSON views to work.  For some reason - probably due to a messy codebase - the opposite was true for me.  To fix the issue, I added the following to my application controller.

```
respond_to :html
```

Now, once again, all is well.